# Create input mask for use in django forms

Tags: jquery, django

Good evening. I'm needing to figure out how to apply input masks in django's forms to a project, however, none of the previous attempts as successful. On the last test: from input_mask.widgets import InputMask However, perhaps for inexperience on my part, when using it not achieved in the desired result. What will be the mistake? Or in another case how do I use other alternatives to deal with this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 7):

Good news! This is actually pretty easy. In your template, make sure you include JQuery as follows:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Then when creating a form field, simply pass the input mask into a field like so:

```
contact_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-mask':"000-000-0000"}))
```

Or if you're using a ModelForm, you can place it in the Meta like so:

```
class Meta:
    model = Booking
    fields = ('date', 'contact_number')

    widgets = {'contact_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-mask':"000-000-0000"})}
```

Check out https://dobsondev.com/2017/04/14/using-jquery-mask-to-mask-form-input/ if you want to get more information on how to use the JQuery masks beyond the simple example given here.

Comment: what if someone is using input fields instead of django forms itself. what can be the solution then?

Comment: You can just add the data-mask attribute directly to the html (as long as the relevant scripts have been included as above), ie: `<input type="text" data-mask="000-000-0000"/>`

You can see a sample jsfiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/igorescobar/x2mhx0Ld/)

Comment: thanks Josh, I resolved it by using jquery in another way.